# "In a C program, How to take a (char array) i.e. a user input string(including spaces), whose length should also be a user input value?

Tags: c

"In a C program, How to take a (char array) i.e. a user input string(including spaces), whose length should also be a user input value ?"

In C program, I tried to take a user input value as the length for a user input string, but did not get the required output. 
[a code snippet of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGhj7.png)

I expect the output to be the same string entered by the user, whose length would also be a user input value.
But the actual output does not show the string, once the user enters the string length.

Comment: You'll get an answer much easier if you post the actual code here, not a link or image of the snippet. Can you also include example input/output?

Comment: Don't use `gets` (it has been deperecated long time ago, 20 years or so, not quite sure). Use `fgets` and `malloc` instead. And please don't post pictures of code, but post the code as text.

Comment: Do you trust the user to **not** input 'length'=5, 'string'="five"?

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the stdin buffer
 after your

```
scanf("%d",&len);
//add to clear the buffer manually after your scanf
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
char str[len+1];
fgets(str, len + 1, stdin);
```

plus its a bad habit to put the code like this in a picture instead of actually posting it

Comment: `char c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` is an infinite loop when `char` is unsigned and end-of-file occurs.  Use `int c;`.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is unknown until runtime (i.e. because it is given by a user input), dynamic allocation is an option:

```
char *input = malloc(len + 1);
fgets(input, len + 1, stdin);

// use `input`...

free(input);
input = NULL;
```

Also, **[never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)**; it is dangerous and not supported by the latest C standard.

Comment: OP's use of _length_ certainly does not consider the inputted `'\n'` as part of the _length_.  Use `len + 1 + 1` instead to read _length_ non-\n-characters and the `'\n'`.